# elasticsearch search is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

This search returns the correct document in kibana.

```
date:"18-01-29" AND time:"00:59:58,809" AND EventType:"ERROR"
```

How do I search the same document in elasticsearch?

I get an error with this search.

```
curl -XGET 'ip:9200/index_name/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(date:18-01-29) AND (EventType:ERROR) AND (time:00\:59\:58,809)"
        }
    }
}
'
"reason" : "Unrecognized character escape ':' (code 58)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3124698d; line: 5, column: 75]"
```

This search does not return the correct document in elasticsearch.

```
curl -XGET 'ip:9200/index_name/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "date": "18-01-29" }},
        { "match": { "time": "00:59:58,809"  }},
        { "match": { "EventType": "ERROR"  }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Your kibana search is an exact phrase search but your query is fuzzier. First try using a [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with the same query to see if that works

Comment: apokryfos thanks, it worked, "(date:\"18-01-29\") AND (EventType:\"ERROR\") AND (time:\"00:59:58,809\")".